# Clipboard.js clipboard.copy() not working inside a Meteor.call() result

Tags: javascript, meteor, clipboard, clipboard.js

When I use the clipboard.copy from clipboard.js inside of a `Meteor.call` it brings the error:

> "Unable to copy. Perhaps it's not available in your browser?"

The way that I am calling it is:

```
Meteor.call "create__course", @email, @cid, (err,ret) ->
    clipboard.copy(ret)
```

The create_course works correctly and if I use the `clipboard.copy("some text")` outside of the `Meteor.call` it works as it should.

I want to be able to copy into the clipboard the result text that comes from the create_course call. I already looked that the value that it brings is a string and it is.